# Help with String

Tags: ms-access, string

Need help with script-string.  An Excel sheet I import into Access has a text field that always starts with a number or range of numbers like: '312' or '312-337'. This field and others are on a form.  I need to open that form with a condition based on the number or range.  So, my Where Condition [Enter Number or Range] = [text field with this number or range].....   Could someone please help me with this second half of the condition of the text field, to open only records based on user entry of the number of range of numbers.

Thank you

Comment: Flagged as offtopic (Stackoverflow). You need to open a form depending on a text field on that particular form? Could you please be more specific and post some code? (How is the sheet imported, when do you want to filter something out etc.)

Comment: You can't use a single parameter to select on a range.

Comment: are your values like '312' and '312-337' or are they all numbers [only] and vary in range? say you import this sheet and you get values like 312, 312, 312, 313 [etc] or are the values already concatenated like 312, 312-344, 313, 313-356, etc

Answer (score 1):

As @David-W-Fenton suggested, this is not possible with a simple query parameter because your operators aren't static.  Meaning, sometimes you'll need to use >= [some #] and <= [some #], whereas other times you want only a specific number, and even other times you'll need a combination of the two.

So, the only way I see to accomplish this is to create the SQL statement and where clause through vba, then set that as the recordsource to your form or query at the OnOpen event.